# how convert a python post call to restsharp

Tags: python, c#

Check the two part of code bellow. There is two method second one is python method which make a post request to a url but i want to do same api call with same payload with c# restsharp. I already tried to convert code like bellow but since i don't have idea about python i am not able to understand how can i add `payload` as its done in python code. I already tried to add this payload using `request.AddBody` but it is not same as it was done in python code. How can i add those `payload` info with restsharp request exactly as done in py? please advice

`payload:`

> data={
> "locationType": "LOCATION_INPUT",
> "zipCode": zip_code,
> "storeContext": "generic",
> "deviceType": "web",
> "pageType": "Gateway",
> "actionSource": "glow",
> "almBrandId": "undefined",
> }

`C#`

```
public static IRestResponse MakeApiCall(string zip_code)
        {

            var client = new RestClient("https://www.example.com");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            //request.AddHeader();//i can add header like this thats not a problem
            //request.AddCookie();//i can add cookie like this thats not a problem

            request.AddBody("data=", @"{" +
            "locationType\": \"LOCATION_INPUT",
            "zipCode\": zip_code,
            "storeContext\": \"generic",
            "deviceType\": \"web",
            "pageType\": \"Gateway",
            "actionSource\": \"glow",
            "almBrandId\": \"undefined");

            var result = client.Execute(request);

            return result;
        }
```

`Python:`

```
def MakeApiCall(zip_code: str, headers: dict, cookies: dict):
    response = requests.post(
        url="https://www.example.com",
        data={
            "locationType": "LOCATION_INPUT",
            "zipCode": zip_code,
            "storeContext": "generic",
            "deviceType": "web",
            "pageType": "Gateway",
            "actionSource": "glow",
            "almBrandId": "undefined",
        },
        headers=headers,
        cookies=cookies,
    )
    assert response.json()["isValidAddress"], "Invalid change response"
    return response.cookies
```

Comment: "i think it is not same" is not a proper description of a problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to convert the method from python into a C# method. I am assuming that you are using .NET Core and the RestSharp library, if not you need to clarify what you are using in your original post.

In your class instantiate the RestClient class in a constructor

```cs
public class RandomClass
{
   private readonly IRestClient _client;
   public RandomClass(){
      _client = new RestClient("baseUrl");
      _client.UseSerializer(
         () => new JsonSerializer { DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFZ" }
      );
   }
}
```

Now, define a class for your request data:

```cs
public class Location {
   public string LocationType {get; set;}
   public string ZipCode {get; set;}
   public string StoreContext {get; set; }
   public string DeviceType {get; set;}
   public string ActionSource {get; set;}
   public string BrandId {get; set;}
}
```

In your `MakeApiCall` method:

```cs
public IRestResponse MakeApiCall(Location data){
   var request = _client.Request("/endpoint/relative/to/baseUrl", Method.POST);
   var jsonToSend = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
   request.AddParameter(
      "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      jsonToSend, 
      ParameterType.RequestBody
   );
   var response = _client.Execute(request);
   if (response.ErrorException != null)
   {
      const string message = "Error retrieving response.";
      throw new Exception(message, response.ErrorException);
   }
   // if we get to here then the request succeeded
   return response.data;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but nonetheless it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about it.

1. Use a strongly typed data structure
2. Create a dynamic object and use that as your data object.

Create a class to store your data object

```
class MyDataType
{
    [JsonProperty("locationType")]
    public string LocationType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("zipCode")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    //...
}

// and in your method, you would use the above datatype like this,
var data = new MyDataType
{
    LocationType = "location",
    ZipCode = "zipCode"
    // ...
};
```

or 2. Create a dynamic / anonymous object and use that as json body.

```
var data = new
{
    locationType = "location",
    zipCode = "zipCode",
    storeContext = "generic",
    deviceType = "web",
    pageType = "Gateway",
    actionSource = "glow",
    almBrandId = "undefined",
};
```

Once you have your object, I would recommend using `AddJsonBody` as `AddBody` is deprecated.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.example.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader(@"Content-Type", @"application/json");
request.AddHeader(@"Accept", @"application/json");

request.AddJsonBody(data);
var result = client.Execute(request);

string actualData = result.Content;
```

`result.Content` would have your response. You can use Newtonsoft Json to convert data in your response to a class object and validate your data that way.